# TypeScript- TypeError: "SampleClass.sampleFunction" is not a function

Tags: typescript, typeerror, cocoscreator

I'm using `Cocos Creator` and `TypeScript` to develop my web based 2D game. I faced the following error while calling `onTapFalse` function.

`Uncaught TypeError: playableObj.onTapFalse is not a function`

here's `onTapFalse`  function:

```
@ccclass('PlayableObject')
export class PlayableObject extends Component {
    public onTapFalse() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I call `onTapFalse` here:

```
@ccclass('CorrectionHandler')
export class CorrectionHandler extends Singleton<CorrectionHandler> {
    public correct(playableObj: PlayableObject){
        if (!playableObj.isTrue)playableObj.onTapFalse();
    }
}
```

What's the solution?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out I passed a parameter of wrong type (a type other than `PlayableObject`) to the `correct` function. So `playableObject.isTrue` was always `false` because of there isn't the `isTrue` in this class, also there isn't the `onTapFalse` function.